# How can I understand if tasks parallelism is efficient in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I think my question it's a very basic/fundamental question in Spark. But  instead of this I think that I've missed something.  All the questions and answers which I found were about extreme cases, with small tasks and only 1-2 outlier tasks. In my case all the tasks "looks good" but how can I be sure?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've taken in to consideration the following, but I'm not sure If I missed something in my analysis

- The **Event Timeline** and  in Duration stats in **Summary Metrics** all the tasks take approximately the same time.
- I have in parallel as many tasks as the number of cores
- There is no gap time between finished and new tasks
- GC time is very low
- The Peak Execution Memory is about 64 MB, so it's a ok
- Locality level = Process Local, so it's perfect!

Dependencies:

```
Spark 2.4.3
Kafka 2.11-2.10
Scala 2.11.8
```

Spark Submit confs:

```
--total-executor-cores=12 (Total machine cores=16)
--spark-executor-cores=6
--executor-memory=25G (Total machine memory=90G)
--spark-default-parallelism=72
--spark-sql-parallelism=72
```

**Extra note:** The number of partitions 72 is 6 * 12. The general rule is 2-3 times, I tested also with 2, 3, 4, 6, 12 * cores. With 2,3,4,6 I had the same execution time and with 12 I had worse. I preferred 6 because it works better in the production system.